# how to remove spacing between navigation bar and the tab

Tags: html, css

I tried for so long to get rid of the spacing , can someone tell what I need to do.
I am new to web development.

Thanks in advance[you can see the white line spacing about my menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYV99.png)

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because the `<body>` tag of your page has a margin. You can remove this with the following CSS:

`html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

The easiest way to figure this out is to use a tool like Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to check your elements of your page. It will quickly show you where your CSS issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Basically.. Just use this CSS

```
#nav {
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
#menu {
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:0;
}
```

Replace nav and menu with you tag, ID, or Class name you used. Since I don't have your code, I can only go so far with customization.

I also just wrote it to close THAT gap.